# HTML source page GET request from browser returns different data then through C#

Tags: c#, html, get, request

I'm trying to get a HTML source through C# using a normal GET request. This returns the page's HTML but not all of it. When I looked up the GET request made from the browser it contained all HTML (the part I'm searching for)

Note, I'm using a cookie container so all cookies are passed through from C#. It are the exact same cookies.

Is there anything I need to add to my Headers, I tried looking up some code and reproduce it myself but I was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers!

Comment: Are you sure, that additional HTML is not added via Javascript?

Comment: I am 100% sure that it isn't added by javascript. As I've simulated the request using a pentesting tool (burp-suite) and this gets the source correctly.